# Tannaka reconstruction: reference request

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, category-theory, representation-theory, monoidal-categories

What is a classical and perhaps even original reference for the following result, often called Tannaka reconstruction?

Let $G$ be a group and $R$ be a commutative ring in which $0,1$ are the only idempotent elements (for example, a field). Then the automorphism group of the tensor functor $U : \mathsf{Rep}_R(G) \to \mathsf{Mod}(R)$ (which forgets the $G$-action) is canonically isomorphic to $G$.

If $R$ is an arbitrary commutative ring, then the automorphism group is $C(\mathrm{Spec}(R),G)$.

Comment: For complex representations, the reference is Tannaka's article *Über den Dualitätssatz der nichtkommutativen topologischen Gruppen* (1938), and Krein also works over $\mathbb{C}$. Maybe Rosenberg's article *Reconstruction of groups* deals with general rings?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi If their proof works verbatim for the general case, I would accept this as an answer.

Comment: I haven't read the proof, but I've seen a sketch during a talk, and it uses the Peter-Weyl theorem and some kind of Fourier analysis, so I don't know if it generalizes readily. BTW, I don't think it's the full $\operatorname{Aut}(U)$ that's isomorphic to $G$, you need some conditions (for example the automorphisms must be monoidal in some sense).

Comment: I wrote "the automorphism group of the tensor functor". If I mean the underlying functor, I would say so. The automorphism group of the underlying functor is $R[G]^{\times}$.

Comment: Ah, I missed that part, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There is the article of Deligne and Milne available here

http://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/tc.pdf

See Proposition 2.8. In the language you use, this is likely to be as classical as it gets.

Comment: Thank you. This is only for the case that $R$ is a field, right? (Not that the general case causes any problems... at least if $G$ is just a discrete group)

Comment: Dear @MartinBrandenburg, It is of course only for fields. My feeling is that the analog for rings is either not true (do you know a proof or reference off the top of your head?) or can be deduced fairly easily from that for fields, but of course I may be wrong about this. Best regards

Comment: If $R$ is any commutative ring, then $\mathrm{Aut}_\otimes(U) \cong C(\mathrm{Spec}(R),G)$ (which is simply $G$ when $R$ has no idempotents $\neq 0,1$). I am sure about this, but don't know a reference in the literature.